# Can I avoid this subshell in a POSIX sh script?

Tags: linux, sh, posix, subshell

I am trying to comprehend how, if even it can be done, can I avoid subshell?

Is this the only way the code can be written or is there another way?

I tried to use braces `{ ... }`, but it won't pass shellcheck and won't run.

```sh
is_running_interactively ()
# test if file descriptor 0 = standard input is connected to the terminal
{
    [ -t 0 ]
}

is_tput_available ()
# check if tput coloring is available
{
    command -v tput > /dev/null 2>&1 &&
    tput bold > /dev/null 2>&1 &&
    tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
}

some_other_function ()
# so far unfinished function
{
    # is this a subshell? if so, can I avoid it somehow?
    ( is_running_interactively && is_tput_available ) || # <-- HERE
    {
        printf '%b' "${2}"
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [compound-list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04), and yes those commands are run in a subshell. To avoid it, use curly braces instead of parentheses:

```
{ is_running_interactively && is_tput_available; } || ...
```

Comment: Oh, I see there needs to be a semi-colon, Thank you.

Comment: Actually *compound command* or technically a *compound list*. (see [POSIX Programmer's Guide](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) and 2-3 pages down for *compound-list* directly)

Comment: @David thanks, updated with correct term and link to the POSIX spec

Comment: No problem. Good use of the brace-enclosed group `{...}` to avoid the subshell.